# Fluent Nhibernate - How to specify table name

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, configuration, fluent-nhibernate

I just started learning Nhibernate and Fluent Nhibernate. I want to specify table name when I create my mapping class.

Entity name in application is "CustomerOrders" but in the oracle database, table name is "CUSTOMER_ORDERS".

I learnt from googling that I can use "WithTable" to specify database table name.

I am not sure how to use it and where as Vs2008 didn't find the method.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WithTable` was renamed to `Table` for the 1.0 release. It was mentioned in the [release notes](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Release_notes_1.0) (first bullet point).

Answer (score 4):

```
public class CustomerOrdersMap : IAutoMappingOverride<CustomerOrders>
    {
        public void Override(AutoMapping<CustomerOrders> mapping)
        {
            mapping.Table("CUSTOMER_ORDERS");


        }
    }
```

Comment: @Thakkar i'm not sure from question how much more you would need specifically, so just ask if you want more context

Comment: Dove, 
Table names and field names contains underscores and I do not have underscores in any entity class name or properties. 

I am not using AutoMapping because of these reason. I am extending from ClassMap manually. 

Now, is there a way to map field names as well with AutoMapping or map to a table name using ClassMap? 

Please advise.

Comment: @Thakkar is there a convention of any kind between properties and table names.  if it was consistant in some way, a convention could be written for it.  for example all my foreign key names have FK as suffix in my databases.

Comment: Dove, field names do not have any name patterns. The underscores appear randomly.
e.g. Table name: Customer_Orders
Field names: ID, Order_ID, Order_Item_ID, Item_Info, Comments, etc..

Unfortunately, I cannot change the database as other existing systems are using it. 

I see a "Table" method in the FluentNHibernate.Mapping.ClassMap. Do you think It will map the class to appropriate table?